# Having a lot of trouble posting my "Notes" field into the database while using the submodal feature

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am having a lot of trouble saving the Notes section from my submodal feature. Everything else saves but the notes will not.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>
 <?php require_once('Connections/cms.php'); ?>
<?php
 if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
 if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
 $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
 }

    $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) :   
 mysql_escape_string($theValue);    
switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

 $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
 $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
 }

 if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "lead_note")) {
 $updateSQL = sprintf ("UPDATE Leads SET Notes = CONCAT_WS('\n', Notes, '\n', %s) WHERE Id=%d",
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['Notes'], "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], "int"));

 mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $cms) or die(mysql_error());

 $updateGoTo = "testleadform.php";
 if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
 header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
 }

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Id'])) {
 $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['Id'];
 }
 mysql_select_db($database_cms, $cms);
 $query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT Id, First_Name, Last_Name, Notes FROM Leads WHERE Id = %s",    
 GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
 $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $cms) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
 $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
 ?>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
function clickSubmit() {

 //$("form").submit();
 // window.opener.document.form1.Notes.value = $('#Notes').text();
  window.parent.hidePopWin();

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table><tr><td>

<div id="lead_box">
 <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="lead_note" id="lead_note"   
 target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; ?>" />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#eeeeee"><p align="center" class="name"></p></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea rows="15" style="width: 99%" readonly><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Notes']; ?></textarea>     
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top"><p class="title">Add Note:</p></td>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <textarea name="Notes" id="Notes" style="width: 99%" rows="5"></textarea>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="lead_note" />
</form>
</div><!-- and of lead box -->
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<div align="right">
<input  type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save" onClick="clickSubmit()"/>
<input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="window.parent.hidePopWin()"/>
</div>
</td></tr></table>



</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: There are none...my only problem is that the field "Notes" will not insert in the database, and every other field will...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) OR [MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql? If you will use PDO you won't need to "clear" variables by your self :

```
switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
   ....
}
```

You can use PDO Prepared statements : [pdostatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Can you please insert `var_dump` here

```
var_dump($_POST);
 $updateSQL = sprintf ("UPDATE Leads SET Notes = CONCAT_WS('\n', Notes, '\n', %s) WHERE Id=%d",
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['Notes'], "text"),
 GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], "int"));
var_dump( $updateSQL,$_POST['Notes']);
```

and let us know, what will be the output ?